# Disable automatic archiving of sent emails

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

When you send an email in Gmail, it is archived in the `Sent` folder.

Is there a way to disable this auto-archiving of sent email inside Gmail?

I.e. All sent emails should be auto-deleted.

Does any of the following email clients allow you to turn off automatic sent email archiving?:

1. Yahoo
2. Hotmail
3. In
4. Rocket mail
5. Squirrelmail

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications Stack Exchange site. Please take the [tour](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn the ropes (software recomendations are out of scope).

Comment: This question would be better without the second paragraph.

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: Where would you like the `Sent` email to go? In the `Inbox`?!

Comment: @w3d No, I don't want there to be a Sent archive

Comment: So you just want the email to "vanish"?! What exactly do you want to happen when you send this email? Sorry, I'm trying to get my head round what you're asking? The concept of "archiving" is different in different email clients. In Gmail an email is "archived" if it's not in the Inbox (ie. does not have the `Inbox` tag). Most conventional email clients don't have the concept of "archiving", but _sent_ email is still usually placed in the "Sent" folder. In some email clients (eg. Thunderbird) you can control which folder _sent_ email is saved to?

Comment: @w3d Yes, I'd like there to be no trace about the emails I sent. I understand that I could go to Sent and delete them from there. But I'd like to avoid manually deleting my sent emails

Comment: Ah, so you really want the email to be auto-deleted once sent, not simply to "disable auto-archiving"? Is this _all_ emails, or only emails to (or from) a particular address?

Comment: @w3d Yup, I'd like Sent emails to be auto-deleted. It could be either for a particular recipient or for all recipients, it does not matter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there is anyway to do this in Gmail. When an email is sent it appears in the "Sent Mail" *folder* (or rather is assigned the `sent` label) and there does not appear to be anyway to change this behaviour. "Filters" only act on incoming email.

However, you can do this in some other email clients, by essentially not saving the sent email:

---

## SquirrelMail

You can set it to simply not use the "Sent" folder. Under Options > Folder Preferences > Special Folder Options > Set "Sent Folder" to "[Do not use Sent]":

[image: SquirrelMail - Special Folder Options]

---

## roundcube

In roundcube you can set this at the time you compose the email, by selecting "- don't save -" from the "Save sent message in" dropdown:

[image: roundcube - Save sent message in]

To make this the default option you can set this in Settings > Preferences > Special Folders and set the "Sent" folder to "---":

[image: roundcube - Special Folders]

---

## Mozilla Thunderbird (desktop email client)

In Thunderbird you can simply uncheck the "Place a copy in" checkbox, with regards to "sending messages" (in the appropriate account settings), and the sent email does not appear to be saved anywhere. The default behaviour is to save the sent email in the Sent folder on the email account.

In Account Settings > Copies & Folders > When sending messages, automatically: > Uncheck "Place a copy in".

[image: Thunderbird Account Settings - Copies & Folders]